# Nag vs. Complain

Tags: meaning, differences, semantics

I read a text in which a guy was complaining to his friend about school. I noticed the title of the passage was "nagging". But as far as I know *nag* means "annoy someone by complaining a lot about *his/her* behavior, appearance, etc."
To me, it means your complaint is addressed to the person you're talking to. As in:
"His wife is always nagging him about his late arrival." Or "His parents are always nagging him to clean his room."
Can we use *nag* in general situations meaning *complain*, as in "He was talking to his friend and nagging about school."

Comment: Have you looked at the meanings of 'Nag' and 'Complain' in a dictionary? Did what you find confirm your suspicions about whether or not they are synonyms in any circumstances?

Comment: ^ Stop nagging. :p No, it sounds like the wrong use of the word, as nagging and complaining are quite different things.

Comment: @MarvMills Yes I looked it up in Merriam Websters Advanced Learners Dictionary, and yes it kinda confirmed my suspicions, but I thought I would ask natives for their opinions!

Comment: @ralph.m Here is another example in Websters Dictionary: "Quit nagging! I already said I'm not going!" The complaint is still addressed to the person, though!

Comment: ^ You mean you had a nagging suspicion it was wrong usage. :p

Comment: @ralph.m That was a good example :D yeah I had a nagging suspicion! The dictionary includes that meaning, too, but as a separate entry!

Comment: You can nag by complaining incessantly. You can't complain by nagging incessantly.

Comment: @Ricky Have you met my wife?

Comment: @MarvMills: No, I haven't had the honor. There are exceptions to every rule. Each woman has her own specialty.

Comment: You should quote the line, with the name of the article/book/website  for all we know the author's choice of title, *nagging*, if it is a title, is correct. In other words, please be more specific than **a guy was complaining to his friend about school.**

Comment: @Mari-LouA A guy is complaining to his friend about school: the school has a small gym for so many students. It also lacks modern educational facilities. These are what the guy is complaining about.

Comment: What exactly does he say? Is it the first time he talks about this problem or is there something in the text which indicates that he has repeatedly made similar complaints. You could leave a link, and just quote the sentence where the guy is *moaning* about the lack of facilities.

Comment: @Mari-LouA it is the first time. But I thought nagging and complaining were different in that when you nag someone about something, there is something bad or hard to take about the person you are talking to. That is you complain constantly to a person about the very same person! Or when you keep asking them to do or not to do something!

Comment: Yeah, well we won't know for sure unless you actually quote the lines. But if you are constantly complaining about something it usually becomes tiresome for the listener, and then s/he might accuse that person of being a *nag* or of *nagging*. Funnily enough, a nag is usually reserved for women. I don't hear of men being called a *nag*.

Answer (score 3):

In reading a few definitions of **nag**, I see that the lexicographers make the meaning broader than I would. When you **nag** someone, you harangue them about things you want them *to do or to stop doing*. It is possible to complain incessantly about something someone has done in the past, something which is over and done with, which cannot be changed. That is not nagging, not as I understand it anyway, but under those definitions it would be.

Comment: I agree. It's possible to say someone is always *complaining* about how you slighted or disadvantaged them years ago, but *nagging* doesn't really work in that context because you're not doing it now, and you can't alter the fact that you *did* do it. Nagging is about trying to change behaviour; complaining is about expressing how you feel.